# Can We Have Class Name Instead Of Return Type In c#?

Tags: c#

Can We Have Class Name Instead Of Return Type  ? If Yes Than How And If No Than How ? , Please Explain Me With This Basic Singleton Pattern

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample s1;
        s1 = Sample.cr();
        Sample s2 = Sample.cr();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }      
}
class Sample
{
    static Sample p;
    private Sample()
    { 

    }
    // Why Here Retrun Type Is Missing I Mean Void / Int ?
    public static Sample cr()
    {
        if(p==null)
        {
            p = new Sample();

        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Your code compiles with no errors or warnings. If it doesn't do what you wanted it to, what *did* you want it to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet in fact, the question essence is comment in code: "// Why Here Retrun Type Is Missing I Mean Void / Int ?"

Comment: Please don't use singletons; they are always a lazy hack to all problems and result in very-hard to test code.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: It's entirely unclear to me what that comment is actually meant to indicate, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suppose OP previously seen only methods having primitive types as return type, so he was confused by the method returning class instance and having "class name as return type" (as is was worded by OP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return type is **not** missing in your sample. Your `cr` method has return type, and it is `Sample`.

Any of your custom class is type too, not only primitive types such as `int`, `string` and so on.

Comment: You Mean To Say That , Here I Am Returning Instance Of Sample , So In Return Type There Is Class Name public static Sample cr()

Comment: Right. You are returning an instance of `Sample`.

Comment: Yes, you're returning instance of Sample, thus return type is `Sample` - this is not only class name, but type also.

Comment: @vivek: What did you think `return p;` was returning?

Comment: @ Andy Korneyev Same As I Said Previously , But I Was Not Sure Of It